# My Ubuntu cannot access to the Internet

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

My Ubuntu cannot access to the Internet whereas my virtual Windows machine on Virtual box, which is installed in my Ubuntu, can. Network configuration of that virtual machine is of type bridge of wlan0. I cannot even ping the default gateway on the wlan0 interface from my Ubuntu but every thing works well in that Windows machine.

Output of `ifconfig wlan0`

```
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:36:dd:14:d2:3c  
      inet addr:172.30.60.188  Bcast:172.30.60.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6236:ddff:fe14:d23c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:332314 errors:0 dropped:54 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:43703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:66076979 (66.0 MB)  TX bytes:5894865 (5.8 MB)
```

Output of `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.30.60.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
81.31.160.0     172.30.60.1     255.255.224.0   UG    10     0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
172.30.60.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
213.233.160.0   172.30.60.1     255.255.224.0   UG    10     0        0 wlan0
```

Note that ping from that Windows machine will be responded very quickly but ping from the Ubuntu will be responded very slowly.

Out of `ping 172.30.60.1`, This is the default gateway.

```
PING 172.30.60.1 (172.30.60.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=62 ttl=255 time=43.4 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=63 ttl=255 time=3.85 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=71 ttl=255 time=4.78 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=82 ttl=255 time=2.44 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=127 ttl=255 time=2.31 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=148 ttl=255 time=154 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=217 ttl=255 time=4.06 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=225 ttl=255 time=2.97 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=333 ttl=255 time=101 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=334 ttl=255 time=71.3 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=473 ttl=255 time=14.5 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=474 ttl=255 time=2.47 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=544 ttl=255 time=10.0 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=585 ttl=255 time=745 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=586 ttl=255 time=488 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=587 ttl=255 time=863 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=589 ttl=255 time=2048 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=590 ttl=255 time=1234 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=591 ttl=255 time=227 ms
64 bytes from 172.30.60.1: icmp_seq=592 ttl=255 time=121 ms
^C
--- 172.30.60.1 ping statistics ---
639 packets transmitted, 20 received, 96% packet loss, time 642600ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.319/307.380/2048.298/523.403 ms, pipe 3
```

As you can see there is 96% packet loss. This problem is pretty weird to me!

Also it might be worth mentioning that my Ubuntu was working fine until I have installed `aircrack-ng` and `wireshark` packages.

**EDIT #1**

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0888] (rev c4)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4262]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Output of `iwconfig`

```
IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Shadmaan"  
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 0A:18:D6:A9:49:FE   
Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:116  Invalid misc:4646   Missed beacon:0
```

**EDIT #2**

The FULL output of `iwconfig`

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Shadmaan"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 0A:18:D6:A9:49:FE   
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:116  Invalid misc:4646   Missed beacon:0

ppp0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; iwconfig` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0"
```

then reboot.

This will disable all problematic options. You can test if all of them are needed by editing `/etc/modprobe/iwlwifi-opt.conf` file.

Comment: This won't help, because my Virtual box uses the same wifi configuration and driver and also works fine. I think the problem is caused at upper layers than  the physical or link layer.

Comment: What is the FULL output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: _FULL_ output was added.

Comment: I do not see any problems. The signal level is a little bit low. That may be a problem. Or interference with other APs in the neighborhood. Maybe change channel in the router.

Comment: That's really weird. Apparently the problem has nothing to do with signal strength and interferences and such. Because my virtual Windows machine (installed on the _same_ Ubuntu)  could communicate with the network very well. I think the problem is because of the differences of how Windows machines communicate with the network and how Linux machines do.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: To my knowledge about networking, I also concur with your opinion. But anyway I don't know why this problem is raised.